# Nuxt 3 project cannot locate PWA icons

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, progressive-web-apps

[DevTools Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3GMu.png)
I'm currently trying to implement PWA functionality into my nuxt 3 project but I keep getting this issue: `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/icon_512x512.png"`. This is the same for all 4 icons that I'm to use for this. The rest of the project works completely fine but its just this one issue.

I've attached the errors from my Chrome DevTools.

Thanks

I've attempted rebuilding and reinstalling the project and plugins respectively, as well as move the location of the icons. Nothing has worked as of yet.